# The (non-)compactness of the space of meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Denote by $H_k$ the space of all holomorphic functions $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ with $k$ prescribed simple poles. How one sees that this space is not compact? Also, I was told that it becomes a compact space once one takes its quotient by the action of $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$. How to see this also?

As for the topology on $H_k$. There are several ways to make $H_k$ into a topological space. For example: if $f\in  H_k$, then let $t_1,\dots,t_{2k-2}$ be the critical values of $f$. We assign to $f$ the polynomial $(t-t_1) \dots (t-t_{2k-2})=t^{2k-2}+c_1t^{2k-3}+\dots+c_{2k-3}t+c_{2k-2}$. So we get a map $H_k\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2k-2}$ defined by $f\mapsto (c_1,\dots, c_{2k-2})$. Now endow the space $H_k$ with the topology with respect to which the above map is continuous.

Comment: if $a_1,\dots,a_k\in\mathbb C\subset \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ are the poles then $f\in H_k$ means $f(z)=g(z)/((z-a_1)\dots(z-a_k))$ with $g$ a polynomial of degree $\leq k$. So $H_k$ is a vector space (of dimension $k+1$), and mod $\mathbb C^*$ you get a projective space. Hence non-compact and compact.

Comment: I just understood, we are assuming $f$ is holomorphic at $\infty$. so $f(z) \prod_i (z-a_i)$ is an entire function bounded by a polynomial, i.e. a polynomial itself

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me whether $H_{k}$ is intended to denote the space of (all) meromorphic functions of degree $k$ (which is suggested by the notation), or the space of meromorphic functions with a specific set of $k$ simple poles (which is suggested by the wording).

In either case, however, $H_{k}$ is a *finite-dimensional complex vector space of positive dimension*, which should immediately handle all three questions (non-compactness, compactness of the projectivization, and the topology).